# What is the purpose of the assemblies in the .Net Core Runtime Environment (KRE) bin folder?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I see a lot of assemblies in the KRE bin folder: `{user path}\.kre\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin`, what is the purpose of these assemblies since these are never referenced?

For instance the `System.Net.Http.dll` assembly: I reference this assembly in my project.json which is then retrieved from nuget and stored to the `{user path}\.kpm\packages` folder and referenced from there, not from the kre bin folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/KRuntime-structure)

Core Principles

There are a number of principles that have contributed to shaping the runtime:

- **The runtime should be as self-contained as possible**. Until the
  runtime has walked the application dependency tree of your
  application it cannot know which of the Core CLR packages you want to
  use, so it cannot load any of them before that. Except for Roslyn,
  since the dependency resolver that uses Roslyn doesn’t actually load
  Roslyn until after the dependencies have been walked.
- Dependency Injection through the entire stack. DI is a core part of the KRuntime, and all libraries we build on top of it.

These .dll files are for KRuntime not for concrete application built on it.